# Draw lines with time delay pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I want to draw multiple lines with a time delay. I'm using for loop to for the x and y coordinates.I'm searching for a solution to draw those lines with a time delay between them(eg 1 second). Here is my code:

```
import pygame,sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900)) 
RED = (230, 30, 30)

background_image = pygame.image.load("image.jpg")
background_image = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (1600,900))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Main loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        # Fill the background
         screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
         x= [60,70,80]
         y= [500,600,700]
         for x,y in zip(x,y):
                pygame.draw.line(background_image, RED,(x,y),(900,1280), 10)
                pygame.display.update()
                pygame.time.delay(10)
# Update the screen
        pygame.display.flip()

`
```

Comment: First, you need to correctly format your code so the indention matches your actual code. Otherwise we'll have to manually edit your code to test it which requires unnecessary time/energy and some guess work which might not even be correct. Second, a questions seeking debugging must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. So you need to add what's wrong with the code you've provided, and in why it's wrong (does it raise an error or do something undesirable etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to draw the lines on the `screen` instead of the `background_image`. 500 milliseconds are a half second (10 ms is a *bit* fast). Also, don't use the same variable names for the lists and the coords.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768)) 
RED = (150, 30, 30)

# Replaced the image with a Surface to test the code.
background_image = pygame.Surface((1024, 768))  
background_image.fill((50, 90, 140))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
xs = [60, 70, 80, 90]
ys = [500, 600, 700, 800]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])

    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        # Draw the lines on the screen not the background.
        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, (x, y), (400, 480), 10)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(500)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

This version is still problematic, because you stop the execution of the rest of the main
loop when the for loop runs. That means you can't quit or handle other events during that time.

I've got a more complex example for you with a timer variable. You subtract the delta time (the time that passed since the last tick) from it and when it's below 0 you add another coordinate to a list which you use for the drawing.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
RED = (120, 30, 30)

background_image = pygame.Surface((1024, 768))
background_image.fill((50, 90, 140))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

xs = [60, 70, 80, 90]
ys = [400, 500, 600, 700]
xys = zip(xs, ys)
startpoints = []  # This holds the current startpoints.

dt = 0
timer = 500  # A countdown timer.

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    timer -= dt  # Decrease timer.
    if timer <= 0:  # If timer < 0 append the next xy coords.
        try:
            # `next` just gives you the next item in the xys zip iterator.
            startpoints.append(next(xys))
        # When the zip iterator is exhausted, clear the
        # startpoints list and create a new zip iterator.
        except StopIteration:
            startpoints.clear()
            xys = zip(xs, ys)
        timer = 500  # Reset the timer.

    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    for x, y in startpoints:  # Loop over the available startpoints.
        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, (x, y), (400, 480), 10)

    pygame.display.flip()
    dt = clock.tick(30)
```

Or you could do kind of the same with a custom event and `pygame.time.set_timer`:

```
add_coord_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(add_coord_event, 500)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == add_coord_event:
            try:
                startpoints.append(next(xys))
            # When the zip iterator is exhausted, clear the
            # startpoints list and create a new zip iterator.
            except StopIteration:
                startpoints.clear()
                xys = zip(xs, ys)
```

Edit: Or better just create the startpoint list before the while loop and use `i` to slice it. Then you don't have to move the items from the iterator to the list.

```
xs = [60, 70, 80, 90]
ys = [400, 500, 600, 700]
startpoints = list(zip(xs, ys))
i = 0  # Current index, used to slice startpoints.

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
increase_index_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(increase_index_event, 500)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == increase_index_event:
            i += 1
            i %= len(startpoints) + 1  # Keep i in the correct range.

    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    for x, y in startpoints[:i]:
        pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, (x, y), (500, 580), 10)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: The last one is the best one. But it makes for me complicated to figure out how to delete the old lines.

Comment: Why do you want to delete them? If you explain a bit more detailed what you want to do, I could provide another example.

Comment: Because I have more than a hundred coordinates in my list. I want the first line visible for a half second before the next line is drawn.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you want to do. Describe your final goal please.

Comment: I think I found the answer. I can't delete a line, so what I can do is every time a line is drawn I do screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0]). The result will be the first line is gone and following line will be drawn.

Comment: Can you post that as another answer or edit the question if it doesn't work yet? I'd like to take a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `time.wait()` but that will just freeze your program for a bit or you could have a variable that holds what time the line should be draw. Basically when you draw the first line have `nextLine = time.clock()+1` and have an if in your loop saying `if time.clock > nextLine:` then draw the next line.